# Do access modifiers always have to be instantiated?

Tags: c#, instances

I've read the msdn.microsoft guides, a example of an acessor is the following:

```
// public class: 
public class Tricycle
{
    // protected method: 
    protected void Pedal() { }

    // private field: 
    private int wheels = 3;

    // protected internal property: 
    protected internal int Wheels
    {
        get { return wheels; }
    }
}
```

It allows me to access the wheels variable in other classes trough Trycicle.Wheels, correct?
But then there are properties, which need to be instantiated and seem to enable some accessing

```
class TimePeriod
{
    private double seconds;

    public double Hours
    {
        get { return seconds / 3600; }
        set { seconds = value * 3600; }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        TimePeriod t = new TimePeriod();

        // Assigning the Hours property causes the 'set' accessor to be called.
        t.Hours = 24;

        // Evaluating the Hours property causes the 'get' accessor to be called.
        System.Console.WriteLine("Time in hours: " + t.Hours);
    }
}
// Output: Time in hours: 24
```

In this example I have to instantiate a TimePeriod object, does this means I can't access the value of 'seconds' variable without instantiating? Why is there such difference between this example and the previous one? What makes it forcing me to instantiate?

I'm not very familiar with these concepts.

Comment: "It allows me to access the wheels variable in other classes trough Trycicle.Wheels, correct?" -- No. You will need an instance, because the property is not `static`.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Thank you, can i use the set acessor in a static property?

Comment: @CésarAmorim yes, a static property can have both `get` and `set` accessors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should research static vs. instance members.

In this example:

```
public class Tricycle {
    public static readonly int Wheels = 3;

    public string Color {get; set;}
}
```

A property of all tricycles is that they have 3 wheels. Therefore, I made the `Wheels` field static, and you can ask for `Tricycle.Wheels`.

However, not every tricycle is the same color, so `Color` is not static, and therefore you need a specific tricycle (an instance) in order to get or set its color.